# Spring Security Jwt cannot send body when authenticated

Tags: rest, spring-security, jwt

My problem is that api endpoints that require authentication send nothing in the response's body. API endpoints that do not require authentication work well.

I created a project to test JWT management in a Java17 and Spring 3.x environment.
API endpoints that do not require authentication work well.

Currently, using the below dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

JwtService:

```java
@Service
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${jwt.secretkey}")
    private String secretKey;
    
    @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
    private long jwtExpiration;
    
    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }
    
    public String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtExpiration))
                .signWith(getSigningKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }
    
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }
    
    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts
                    .parser()
                    .setSigningKey(getSigningKey())
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSigningKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
    
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    public SecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter,
            AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                        req.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated()
                        )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JwtService jwtService, 
                                    UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, 
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
                                                throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String username;
        if(authHeader==null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(username==null  && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, 
                        null, 
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

AuthenticationService:

```java
@Service
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public AuthenticationService(UserRepository userRepository, 
                                PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, 
                                JwtService jwtService, 
                                AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> register(RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        User user = new User(registerRequest.getUsername(), registerRequest.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()), Role.USER);
        userRepository.save(user);
        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = new AuthenticationResponse(jwtToken);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationResponse);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername()).orElseThrow();
        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = new AuthenticationResponse(jwtToken);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationResponse);
    }
    
}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public ApplicationConfig(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User nor found"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: this type of authentication does not exist in spring security, handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended, so why are you building a custom non recommended made up security solution instead of actually following the documentation. This is some made up security from some random blog bad blogpost.

Answer (score -1):

In your `JwtAuthenticationFilter`, the only place where you continue the chain is is the auth header is null or doesn't start with `"Bearer "`. You need to do `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` once you have authenticated the token.

Also, I would highly recommend removing the `filterChain.doFilter(...)` call in cases where the auth header is missing, that is a very big security risk.